# How in spatie/laravel-medialibrary get dimensions of uploaded image?

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

Using `spatie/laravel-medialibrary` 8 in Laravel 8 app I wonder if there is a way to get dimensions(width*height)
of uploaded image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the code.

Spatie [MediaLibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) uses spatie [Image](https://github.com/spatie/image) package behind the scenes to generate responsive Images.

Since the [image](https://spatie.be/docs/image/) package has a option to get the [Image Properties](https://spatie.be/docs/image/v1/usage/retrieving-properties)

So you can do Something like this.

```
$fullPathToImage = 'your-path-here';

$imageInstance = Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\ImageFactory::load($fullPathToImage);


$imageWidth = $imageInstance->getWidth();
$imageHeight = $imageInstance->getHeight();
```

since I have't tested the code. But it will provide you some sort of starting point to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

there is no such a feature from the box, but it's possible to get dimensions using the spatie/image component (which is a dependency) like this.

here is the working code from my project:

```
use Spatie\Image\Image;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        $model = \App\Models\MyModel::find($id);

        $image = Image::load($request->file->getPathname());

        $width = $image->getWidth();
        $height = $image->getHeight();

        $media = $model->addMediaFromRequest('file')
            ->toMediaCollection($collectionName);

        // ...
    }
}
```

link to details: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/discussions/2682